# target class interface is not instantiable while building

Tags: laravel, design-patterns, laravel-9

i am using design patterns repository and i wrote every thing coorect but i have an error returns
Target [App\Repository\categoryRepositoryInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController]. i dont know why although i wrote every thing correct please help

here is my code

my config/app

```
    App\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider::class,
```

and my categorycontroller

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repository\categoryRepositoryInterface;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    private categoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository;

    public function __construct(categoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository)
    {
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    }
```

and my repositoryinterface

```
    <?php

namespace App\Repository;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

interface categoryRepositoryInterface 
{
    public function createCategory(Request $request);

    public function validation(Request $request);
    
}
```

and my category repository

```
    <?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class categoryRepository implements categoryRepositoryInterface{

    public function validation(Request $request){
        $validation = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name' => 'required',
        ]);


        if($validation->fails()){
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 400,
                'errors' => $validation->errors(),
            ]);
        }
    }
    
    public function createCategory(Request $request)
    {

            $category = new Category();
            $category->name = $request->name;
            $category->save();        
    }

}
```

and my servicerepositoryprovider

```
    <?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Repository\CategoryRepository;
use App\Repository\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(CategoryRepositoryInterface::class, CategoryRepository::class);
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typos in your `RepositoryServiceProvier`

```php
use App\Repository\categoryRepository;    //First alphabet should be lower case
use App\Repository\categoryRepositoryInterface;  //First alphabet should be lower case 
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {

    //First alphabet should be lower case as per your class and interface names
        $this->app->bind(categoryRepositoryInterface::class, categoryRepository::class);
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Would like to give you a piece of advice. When developing with Laravel it would be easier for you to follow Laravel's naming conventions - Laravel conventions overall. Following conventions will help you better understand examples on the internet as well.

Whatever you decide remember to follow them with consistency. In this particular case you are naming classes in camel case starting with small alphabet so when importing via **use** statements you need to stick to that.